# .png image fail to do binary gray, while .jpg image can

Tags: python, computer-vision, png, jpeg, grayscale

Very easy code, I can read image from either image1 as png or image2 as jpg. Same image with different format.

Then filter out the darker part into black, show the brighter part into white.

```
#image = mpimg.imread('image1.png')
image = mpimg.imread('image2.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
thresh = (180, 255)
binary = np.zeros_like(gray)
binary[(gray > thresh[0]) & (gray <= thresh[1])] = 1
```

Somehow, when I plot the binary of image1, it is all black, but image2 looks what I tend to do. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely due to `matplotlib.image` successfully reading the `png` while the `jpg` falls back to using `Pillow`. The image resulting from the `png` read will be an array of floating point values with a range of 0.0 to 1.0 while the `jpg` read will be an array of bytes with values 0..255. As a result your clip operation will result in an all black image as everything is below 1.

See http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html for more information.

Comment: You are right, I just print out image[0,0,:], the png are all [0:1], the jpg are all [0:255].